# How can I calculate number of buses based on changing trials of customers which have been calculated using Norminv function of excel?

Tags: vba, excel

[image: Example sheet]

Above is the link for picture of excel sheet of the types and capacity of vehicle the company has.
Now how many buses, cars and vans will be required to transport 258 customers while minimizing cost and considering the fact that the value of the cell will keep on changing since it has been calculated using NORMINV function of Excel. I have used several methods but none works.

Comment: Please include the picture in your question. Also, try Goal Seek or Solver.

Comment: @vacip solver and goal seek takes only current value of the cell. But in this case the value of the cell keeps on changing based on normal distribution

Comment: Sorry, I just can't understand what you are on about. "the value of the cell will keep on changing" Which cell are you talking about?

Comment: Number of customers' different trial values. I mean this row Customers 144 251 44 24 -56 89 52 73 96 186 78. The
 cell having value 144 will be something else next time since it has been calculated using NORMINV function NORMINV(rand(),mean,stdev)

Comment: If you want to solve something that has no dependency on the cell containing 144 (which isn't shown in your question??) don't include that cell in the formulas you are using to calculate the answer that you are solving for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since minibus is the cheapest per capita, fill up minibuses with customers, then pack the remainder into a single vehicle they fit (2 cars more expensive then one anything, 2 vans more expensive then one minibus -> always use just one thing to transport the remainder).

Use the QUOTIENT, MOD and nested IF functions (or a VLOOKUP, but in this case I'll go with IFs for simplicity).

I have done a bit dirty job, but I think you have got the idea.

[image: HomeworkForFar]

If you want a single formula, just combine them together:

```
=IF(MOD(B6;QUOTIENT(B6;C2)*B2)>6;IF(MOD(B6;QUOTIENT(B6;C2)*B2)>20;B2;B4);B3)+QUOTIENT(B6;C2)*B2
```

Comment: No problem, this was and interesting problem.